# How can my 2 subdomains create more value for each other?

Tags: google, google-adsense

I have a domain example.com that has 2 entities

**www.example.com**

This is my product's website. It has great content and is updated periodically by additions to the blog.

- Sessions per day: 150
- Indexed pages: 238
- Links to the site: 347

The links are generally pretty good quality. There are a few sites where I'm not sure what they are.

**support.example.com**

This is actually a web application that provides information that's stored in a database. There's good content that surrounds the info from the database. Things are set up so that the pages will be found for very specific queries (e.g. "How do I change the oil filter on a 1987 Ford Mustang").

The information in this app is translated into 34 languages. Because of that, and all of the combinations of data coming from the database, the site theoretically has 723K pages. I also build the URLs so they look like you're accessing an HTML page and are very readable.

- Sessions per day: 1700  (just about all from searches)
- Indexed pages: 575K
- Links to the site: negligible

All of the support pages have links back to the www site.

So what's the question?

Well, I checked my PageRank and saw that it was 0 and became concerned. I started to look at all of the metrics on the sites and try to understand this. However, on further review I see that newer websites will always have a 0 PageRank (or at least that's what gets reported).

So the question is broader: is what I'm doing reasonable? I'm a bit concerned about the links from support to www. Because there's so many of them, is it possible that Google will see this as an attempt to game the system?

The support site is also currently ad free. If I start serving AdSense ads, will Google give it a little push to attract more visitors?

In general, is there anything else I can do to have these 2 sites create more value for each other?

Comment: We get this a lot!! PR is no longer made publicly available and has not for years. Anything reporting a PR is just flat-out misleading you! Do not worry about it. Do not chase a bogus number. What matters is how people find your site today, what they do on your site today, and whether they will come back tomorrow. Keep it that simple.

Comment: Yes, after doing a little digging I figured this out myself. But I'm still left with the question of whether I'm doing as well as I can from a Google point of view. Yes, I know good content and good links are the best. But is there anything else I can do with these 2 subdomains (or anything I shouldn't be doing) given the metrics I've presented?

Comment: Do you really need two subdomains connecting to each other? I found speed improvements on my site when subdomains didn't connect to each other. Instead I used folder names stemming off the main domain.

Comment: You have a point. The 2 subdomains are separate because they were developed at 2 different times for 2 different purposes. The www subdomain is a WordPress site that's statically hosted while the support subdomain is a Tomcat webapp hosted on EC2. I guess they could both be combined and run on EC2 if I figured out how to massage the URLs so they don't conflict. Do you think this would be overall beneficial?

Comment: The only valuable set of metrics on any site is what Google and Bing can offer. The online performance sites cannot do this for you. BTW- if you put ads on a site, Google does not give more or less traffic. They will completely refresh your site in their index. I would be thinking about moving the support sub-domain to a /sub-directory if I thought the content would not be pinged by Panda, Penguin, etc. There are a fair number of considerations of course.